# Mass delete rows that do not meet criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of product IDS i want to keep, 740 of them. Each product ID is associated with numerous descriptions and information that I need to keep.

I have another list with 2000 Product IDs. 740 of my original Product IDs from above are in this list.

I need to use VBA to find all of the product IDs in the bigger list (2000) and delete the rows that have product IDs that do not exist in the smaller list (740).

The reason i need this done is because the smaller list is linked to a model driven app that I am trying to migrate data into. However, the identifier of the record in the app is not the same kind of identifier in the raw data set, so i can not line them up unless the raw data is I have only the product IDs I need.

Comment: Where is the code you are starting with? Please include it in your question.

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions similar to this - some of them are listed under "Related" on the right of this page.  If you have a list of wanted ID's you can use `Match()` to determine whether a row needs to be deleted on not.